How to handle and download mediagroup using aiogram3?
For 10 hours I was inventing a bicycle, overlapping with various crutches and my own solutions, but no adequate and working options were found (either duplication of event processing, which did not suit me when working with the database and saving images, or downloading only the first mediagroup item).
Later I started to study the documentation and just couldn't find a solution either there or anywhere else on the internet (including GitHub) that would allow me to conveniently download mediagroup items via bot (i.e. from 2 to 10 photos, or videos, or photos and videos). I need this as part of creating a post suggestion for my telegram channel.
Please suggest a short concise solution for handling mediagroups and saving their elements locally
p.s. earlier versions of aiogram allowed somehow more detailed work with mediagroup and contained filters, but aiogram3 still has rather poor functionality

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
